# Algorithm to create an image of an elliptical brush?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, java-2d

I need to be able to accept elliptical(computed) brush parameters such as spacing, hardness, roundness, angle and diameter and then compute a bitmap image based on those attributes.

Does anyone know the algorithm(or where I can find it) to do this?  I have limited experience in graphics programming and I have been unable to find it so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing you want to use a library for, most likely the [Java 2D API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/). It includes facilities for fills, strokes, transforms, and filters. Its model is similar to many libraries in that you trace out a path with operators `moveTo` and `lineTo` or `curveTo`, which are abstracted in shapes like `Ellipse2D`; and then you fill or stroke the resultant path with a paint operator. I highly recommend reading the Java 2D tutorial and understanding how the different parts fit together.

I would take roughly the following steps to create this drawing:

- Compute the final dimensions of the rotated ellipse after blurring.
- Create a `BuferredImage` of that size and call its `createGraphics` method to acquire a drawing context.

  - Rotate the graphics object
  - Draw the ellipse
  - Fill it with black
- Implement the Gaussian blur filter. This is not built in to the API, but it includes a framework for doing filters called `ConvolveOp`, and [you can find](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html) an algorithm for computing the Gaussian kernel in Java.
- Apply the filter to the image, and then return the results.

Another option might be Apache’s [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) SVG library, since you can declaratively express the drawing you want (including transformations and filters) and have it rasterized for you.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely useful list of formulas for an ellipse can be found here: [Link](http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/Ellipse_dir/ellipse.html)

Think about what each formula implies about an individual pixel in your bitmap (whether it's in/out of the ellipse, whether it's near the edge) and which properties would be useful to you.